# number of seconds to years-months-weeks-days-HH:MM-SS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datetime, date-format, date-math

I am running this all the time to get HH:MM:SS from a number of seconds:

```
DECLARE @s INT
SELECT
    @s = 23251
SELECT
    @s
  , CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(SECOND, @s, 0));
```

[image]

when I want to add `days` to the equation I run the following query:

```
DECLARE @seconds AS int = 232511;
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, (@seconds / 86400))                --Days
    + ':' +
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss, @seconds, 0), 108);    --Hours, Minutes, Seconds
```

[image]

what if I wanted as well the number of `weeks`, `months`, and `years`?

How would I go around that?

I think the exact calculation would need to have a reference to `when` the number of seconds happened.

Let's say for instance I am interested in how long a sql server job has been running for. I have jobs within the replication category that have been running for years, and the starting point is known.

When not specified we could assume the number of seconds are up to `now`.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19298644/4406684) is really good as far as being clear and easy to see how to scale it out to weeks, etc. but I am wondering how you determine the length of a "month" since that is not static.

Comment: I think the exact calculation would need to have a reference to `when` the number of seconds happened.

Comment: Months would be tough only because there isn't a distinct value for a month.  If you define a month to be exactly 30 days, in the context of whatever you are measuring, then the calculation is fairly simple.

Comment: You can get the number of days in a month by the function EOMONTH(date). But you'd need the starting date of the time entered as Marcello mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know `@Seconds` and `@StartDateTime`, something like the following could work:

```
 DECLARE @Seconds INT = 50000000;
 DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME2(7) = GETDATE();

 -- Get the EndDateTime
 DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME2(7) = DATEADD([SECOND], @Seconds, @StartDateTime);

 -- Make a one-row CTE of useful info for logic and math later
 WITH Calendar_CTE
      AS (SELECT @StartDateTime AS [StartDateTime]
               , CONVERT(DATE, @StartDateTime) AS [StartDate]
               , DATEPART(YY, @StartDateTime) AS [StartYear]
               , DATEPART(MM, @StartDateTime) AS [StartMonth]
               , DATEPART(DD, @StartDateTime) AS [StartDay]
               , @EndDateTime AS [EndDateTime]
               , CONVERT(DATE, @EndDateTime) AS [EndDate]
               , DATEPART(YY, @EndDateTime) AS [EndYear]
               , DATEPART(MM, @EndDateTime) AS [EndMonth]
               , DATEPART(DD, @EndDateTime) AS [EndDay]
               , DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YY, @EndDateTime), DATEPART(MM, @EndDateTime), 1)) AS [EndLastOfPreviousMonth]),
      -- Another one-row CTE, this time with each DATEPART's differences
      Differences
      AS (SELECT [EndYear] - [StartYear] - CASE
                                             WHEN [EndMonth] < [StartMonth] THEN 1
                                             ELSE 0
                                           END AS [YearDiff] -- If EndMonth is less than StartMonth, subtract 1 Year from the naive differnce
               , CASE
                   WHEN [EndMonth] >= [StartMonth] THEN [EndMonth] - [StartMonth] - CASE
                                                                                      WHEN [EndDay] < [StartDay] THEN 1
                                                                                      ELSE 0
                                                                                    END -- If EndMonth >= StartMonth -> If EndDay is greater than StartDay, subtract 1 Month from the naive differnce
                   ELSE 12 - ( [StartMonth] - [EndMonth] ) -- If EndMonth < StartMonth, subtract the difference from 12
                 END AS [MonthDiff]                    -- e.g. this May to next March: 12 - (5 - 3) = 12 - 2 = 10 months
               , CASE
                   WHEN [EndDay] >= [StartDay] THEN [EndDay] - [StartDay] -- If EndDay >= StartMonth, then take a simple differnce
                   ELSE DATEDIFF(DD, DATEFROMPARTS([EndYear], [EndMonth] - 1, [StartDay]), [EndLastOfPreviousMonth]) + [EndDay] -- If EndDay < StartDay, find the remaining difference to the previous end-of-month, then add the rest of the days to the EndDate (this accounts for differnt length months)
                 END AS [DayDiff]                                                                                   -- e.g. Jan 30th to Feb 2nd: (Jan 31st - Jan 30th) + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3 days
               , @Seconds / 60 / 60 % 24 AS [HourDiff]                                                              -- e.g. Jun 29th to Jul 2nd: (Jun 29th - Jun 30th) + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3 days 
               , @Seconds / 60 % 60 AS [MinuteDiff]
               , @Seconds % 60 AS [SecondDiff]
          FROM [Calendar_CTE])

     -- Put it all together
      SELECT CONCAT([YearDiff], ' Year(s), ', [MonthDiff], ' Month(s), ', [DayDiff] / 7, ' Week(s), ', [DayDiff] % 7, ' Day(s), ', [HourDiff], ' Hour(s), ', [MinuteDiff], ' Minute(s), ', [SecondDiff], ' Second(s)') AS [TimeElapsed]
      FROM [Differences];
```

Comment: Wonderful @Steven - thanks for your time and effort to put all this together

Comment: That 'll gives [wrong results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a078a2008ea26bfc8324f0b4c2bcaf3a). eg: when start is `'2020-01-01 23:59:01'` and end is `'2020-01-02 00:00:01'`

Answer (score 0):

I also did some developments, but it is nothing comparing with [Steven Hibble](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/87965/steven-hibble) solution above.

I left the output in [Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language).

```
DECLARE @Seconds INT = 50000000;
--select @seconds = 896434

select
 [Running For] = CASE WHEN RADHE.YEARS > 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.YEARS AS VARCHAR ) + ' Anni ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.MONTHS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.MONTHS AS VARCHAR ) + ' Mesi ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.WEEKS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.WEEKS AS VARCHAR ) + ' Settimane ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.DAYS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.DAYS AS VARCHAR ) + ' Giorni ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.HOURS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.HOURS AS VARCHAR ) + ' Ore ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.MINUTES> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.MINUTES AS VARCHAR ) + ' Minuti ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.SECONDS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.SECONDS AS VARCHAR ) + ' Secondi ' ELSE '' END 

    FROM   (
                                SELECT      FLOOR ( UpTime / 31207680 ) AS YEARS
                                        ,   FLOOR( (UpTime / 2600640 ) - FLOOR ( UpTime / 31207680  )  * 12 ) AS MONTHS
                                        ,   FLOOR( (UpTime / 604800 ) - FLOOR ( UpTime / 2600640 )  * 4.3 ) AS WEEKS
                                        ,   FLOOR( (UpTime / 86400 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 604800 ) * 7 ) AS DAYS
                                        ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 3600 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 86400 ) * 24 ) AS HOURS
                                        ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 60 )   - FLOOR( UpTime / 3600 ) * 60 ) AS MINUTES
                                        ,   UpTime - FLOOR( UpTime / 60 ) * 60 AS SECONDS

                                FROM        ( 

                                                SELECT @seconds AS UpTime 



                                             ) AS RadheX


                      ) Radhe
```

[image]

Steves output for the same parameter:

[image]

there are 2 days difference.

I found [another solution here](http://www.sqlrelease.com/convert-number-into-year-month-day-hour-minute-and-second).

but whenI run the code I get the following output:

```
DECLARE @VARDT DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, 50000000, 0)
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @VARDT) - 1900 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' year(s) ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @VARDT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' month(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(DD, @VARDT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' day(s) ' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @VARDT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' hour(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @VARDT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' minute(s) ' + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, @VARDT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' second(s)'
```

[image]

even using C#, and doing a calculation as you can see on the picture below:
[image]

there are always some days difference.